# spyOn $scope.$on after $broadcast toHaveBeenCalled fails

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, events, angularjs-scope, jasmine

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this simple test working.

I've got an `$scope.$on` listener in a controller that I want to test. I just want to make certain it's called after a broadcast event.

To do this, I thought the following code would work:

```
describe("Testing the parent controller: ", function() {
    var scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("myApp");

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            ctrl = $controller('parent-ctrl', {
                $scope: scope,
            });
        });
    });


    it ("should trigger broadcast when current page updates", function() {
        spyOn(scope, "$on");
        scope.$broadcast("myEvent", 999);
        expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

It doesn't (`Expected spy $on to have been called.`).  I've dug through numerous examples:

- [How do I test an event has been broadcast in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352636/how-do-i-test-an-event-has-been-broadcast-)
  in-angularjs
- [How do I test $scope.$on in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441782/how-do-i-test-scope-on-in-angularjs)
- [How can I test events in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272414/how-can-i-test-events-in-angular)
- [unit test spy on $emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383607/unit-test-spy-on-emit)
- [How do I unit test $scope.broadcast, $scope.$on using Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181032/how-do-i-unit-test-scope-broadcast-scope-on-using-jasmine)
- [How do I test $scope.$on in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441782/how-do-i-test-scope-on-in-angularjs)
- [How can I test Broadcast event in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757503/how-can-i-test-broadcast-event-in-angularjs)

and learned a lot, but for some reason I'm just not making some critical connection.

I have noticed that the `$on` handler does respond post-assertion, which is unhelpful.  I've tried `scope.$apply()` and `.andCallThrough()` in various configurations but nothing seems to work.

How is this done?

Comment: shouldn't you call $digest() in your scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the event is broadcasted it is the listener function that was registered with `$on` that is executed, not the `$on` function itself.

Your current test would work for code like this, which is probably not what you have:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function () {
    $scope.$on('whatever', someFn);
});
```

What you should be testing is whatever your registered listener function is doing.

So if you for example have:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function() {
  myFactory.doSomething();
});
```

Test it like this:

```
spyOn(myFactory, "doSomething");
scope.$broadcast("myEvent");

expect(myFactory.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: It think a `scope.$digest()` is still needed after the `$broadcast`.

Comment: Not to get the listener function to run, but you are right that it might be needed, depending on what the code in the listener does.

Comment: Thanks @tasseKATT up at 6AM on a Saturday to give this a try :)

Comment: ...and we have a breakthrough.  Your examples were spot-on, short, and clear. Thank you!